# Scatter plot color and clickData mismatch

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, scatter-plot, scatter

I'm trying to make interactive graphs based on `hover_data` and using this [doc](https://dash.plotly.com/interactive-graphing) for reference. And below is code from this doc.

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

df = pd.read_csv('https://plotly.github.io/datasets/country_indicators.csv')


app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([

        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                df['Indicator Name'].unique(),
                'Fertility rate, total (births per woman)',
                id='crossfilter-xaxis-column',
            ),
            dcc.RadioItems(
                ['Linear', 'Log'],
                'Linear',
                id='crossfilter-xaxis-type',
                labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block', 'marginTop': '5px'}
            )
        ],
        style={'width': '49%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                df['Indicator Name'].unique(),
                'Life expectancy at birth, total (years)',
                id='crossfilter-yaxis-column'
            ),
            dcc.RadioItems(
                ['Linear', 'Log'],
                'Linear',
                id='crossfilter-yaxis-type',
                labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block', 'marginTop': '5px'}
            )
        ], style={'width': '49%', 'float': 'right', 'display': 'inline-block'})
    ], style={
        'padding': '10px 5px'
    }),

    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(
            id='crossfilter-indicator-scatter',
            hoverData={'points': [{'customdata': 'Japan'}]}
        )
    ], style={'width': '49%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'padding': '0 20'}),
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='x-time-series'),
        dcc.Graph(id='y-time-series'),
    ], style={'display': 'inline-block', 'width': '49%'}),

    html.Div(dcc.Slider(
        df['Year'].min(),
        df['Year'].max(),
        step=None,
        id='crossfilter-year--slider',
        value=df['Year'].max(),
        marks={str(year): str(year) for year in df['Year'].unique()}
    ), style={'width': '49%', 'padding': '0px 20px 20px 20px'})
])


@app.callback(
    Output('crossfilter-indicator-scatter', 'figure'),
    Input('crossfilter-xaxis-column', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-yaxis-column', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-xaxis-type', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-yaxis-type', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-year--slider', 'value'))
def update_graph(xaxis_column_name, yaxis_column_name,
                 xaxis_type, yaxis_type,
                 year_value):
    dff = df[df['Year'] == year_value]

    fig = px.scatter(x=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == xaxis_column_name]['Value'],
            y=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Value'],
            hover_name=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Country Name']
            )

    fig.update_traces(customdata=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Country Name'])

    fig.update_xaxes(title=xaxis_column_name, type='linear' if xaxis_type == 'Linear' else 'log')

    fig.update_yaxes(title=yaxis_column_name, type='linear' if yaxis_type == 'Linear' else 'log')

    fig.update_layout(margin={'l': 40, 'b': 40, 't': 10, 'r': 0}, hovermode='closest')

    return fig


def create_time_series(dff, axis_type, title):

    fig = px.scatter(dff, x='Year', y='Value')

    fig.update_traces(mode='lines+markers')

    fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False)

    fig.update_yaxes(type='linear' if axis_type == 'Linear' else 'log')

    fig.add_annotation(x=0, y=0.85, xanchor='left', yanchor='bottom',
                       xref='paper', yref='paper', showarrow=False, align='left',
                       text=title)

    fig.update_layout(height=225, margin={'l': 20, 'b': 30, 'r': 10, 't': 10})

    return fig


@app.callback(
    Output('x-time-series', 'figure'),
    Input('crossfilter-indicator-scatter', 'hoverData'),
    Input('crossfilter-xaxis-column', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-xaxis-type', 'value'))
def update_y_timeseries(hoverData, xaxis_column_name, axis_type):
    country_name = hoverData['points'][0]['customdata']
    dff = df[df['Country Name'] == country_name]
    dff = dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == xaxis_column_name]
    title = '<b>{}</b><br>{}'.format(country_name, xaxis_column_name)
    return create_time_series(dff, axis_type, title)


@app.callback(
    Output('y-time-series', 'figure'),
    Input('crossfilter-indicator-scatter', 'hoverData'),
    Input('crossfilter-yaxis-column', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-yaxis-type', 'value'))
def update_x_timeseries(hoverData, yaxis_column_name, axis_type):
    dff = df[df['Country Name'] == hoverData['points'][0]['customdata']]
    dff = dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]
    return create_time_series(dff, axis_type, yaxis_column_name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

With this code, every dots colored blue and I want to color dots based on Country name and I added to fig as below:

```
    fig = px.scatter(x=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == xaxis_column_name]['Value'],
        y=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Value'],
        hover_name=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Country Name'],
        color=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Country Name']        
        )
```

But after adding color, it didn't return exact Country name when hover over dots.

Before adding color:
[image]

After adding color:
[image]

What should I do in this case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hovertext` instead of `customdata` : just replace the occurrences in `dcc.Graph()` and in the callbacks, and remove the line

```py
fig.update_traces(customdata=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Country Name'])
```

This is because `hovertext` refers to the `hover_name` value of the data point being hovered, which in your case is the country name.

Actually, `hoverData` already receives (in callbacks) the 'x', 'y', and 'hover_name' data from the figure, so you would refer to `customdata` only in cases when you need other information set via `custom_data` or `hover_data`, for example in the function update_graph() :

```py
country = dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Country Name']

dff = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == xaxis_column_name]['Value'].values,
    'y': dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Value'].values,
    'country': country,
    'other': country.map('TEST : {}'.format), # another column 
})

fig = px.scatter(x='x', y='y',
                data_frame=dff,
                hover_name='country',
                color='country',
                custom_data=['other']
)
```

... would let you retrieve data from `other` in the callbacks :

```py
country_name = hoverData['points'][0]['hovertext']
other = hoverData['points'][0]['customdata'][0]
# [0] because 'other' is the first element in custom_data list.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've changed to `hovertext` instead of `customdata` and it worked.